# how can I restart a node js file through another node js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried to run a node js through another node js, by killing the port first and then used "node sample.js"
//sample2.js file as :

```
var port =89;
var nodeparam = "sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:port`,node sample.js";
var ls = nodeparam.split(",");
for(let l of ls){
  child = exec(l,function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('started stdout: '+l +"        " + stdout);
    console.log('started stderr: ' +l +"        "+ stderr);
   
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error  started not null: ' +l +"        "+ error);
    }
});
```

but it showing error messages.. So please help me to restart sample.js in any other way through node js code

Comment: What error messages?

Comment: how do you expect "port" to work in line 2?

Comment: i am using port 3999 for running that sample .js  , listening to this port

Comment: started stderr: node cronsetup.js        Killed

exec error  started not null: node sample.js        Error: Command failed: node sample.js
Killed

Comment: when I execute it through cmd as node sample.js and killing through code success .
But i want it through code itself.Is it possible ?

Comment: problem solved,this is an asynchronous thats why its not executing in an  order , before stoping the running node its going to start the same .so its fall into error .  
I used ";"and for stoping the process I used ps-node ,through this I took process pid

Answer (score 0):

I tried in this way , using ps.lookup I take the pid of the running node.
then ,I tried in this way , using ps.lookup I take the pid of the running node.
then ,

```
var nodeparam = "kill -9 <pid>;node sample.js";
    child = exec(nodeparam,function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('" stdout:  + stdout);
    console.log("stderr:"+ stderr);
   
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log("exec error"+ error);
    }
});
```